# Measurability of $1/f$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure

> Let , $f:E\to \mathbb R$ be measurable and $f(x)\not=0$ in $E$. Then show that $1/f$ is measurable on $E$.

Let , $\alpha$ be any real number. Then ,

$$E\left(\frac{1}{f}>\alpha\right)=\begin{cases}E(f>0) &\text{ if } \alpha=0\\E(f>0)\cap E\left(f<\frac{1}{\alpha}\right) &\text{ if } \alpha>0\\E\left(f<\frac{1}{\alpha}\right) &\text{ if }\alpha<0\end{cases}$$

As each set of the R.H.S. is measurable so $1/f$ is measurable.

Please verify the calculation of $E\left(\frac{1}{f}>\alpha\right)$.

Comment: A conceptual generalization is that: the compose of measurable maps is measurable. Explicitly, if $(X_j,\mathfrak M_j)$ are measurable spaces for $j=1,2,3$, and $f\colon X_1\to X_2,g\colon X_2\to X_3$ are measurable, so is $g\circ f$. In addition, continuous functions between topological spaces are Borel measurable.

Comment: And here's a caveat: $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is Lebesgue measurable, which means that $f\colon(\mathbb R,\mathcal B_{\mathbb R})\to(\mathbb R,\mathcal L^1)$ is measurable, where $B_{\mathbb R}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb R$, and in general the composite of two real measurable functions is NOT measurable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first two lines are correct. But if $\alpha < 0$ and $1 / f > \alpha$, you either have

$$ f > 0 $$

or

$$ f < 1 / \alpha $$

So you are missing some things in the third line.

Comment: Ohh..yes.. so it will be $E(f>0)\cup E(f<1/\alpha)$. Is it ?

Comment: )) But in my book it is given that the 3rd line is $E(f>0)\cup E(f<0) \cap E(f<1/\alpha)$. How it is?

Comment: Your first comment is right, so is you second. If $\alpha < 0$, then $1/\alpha < 0$, so $E(f < 1/\alpha) \subset E(f < 0)$, and so $(E (f < 0) \cap E(f < 1/\alpha)) = E(f < 1/\alpha)$. I am not quite sure why your book insists on including that extra (pretty much useless) factor of $E(f < 0)$, but it doesn't make your first comment wrong.

Comment: (BTW, I am guessing that the notation $E(f > 0)$ means "the subset of $E$ consisting of points $x$ at which $f(x) > 0$". If it means something else, please let me know because that may effect the answer.)

Comment: Yes. $E(f>0)=\{x\in E:f(x)>0\}.$ So it does not affect the answer. Right? I agree with your 1st comment. Here the term $E(f<0)$ is useless. But my book includs that extra term & that's why my confusion arises.

Comment: Let's put it this way: we've already agreed that [your answer is correct](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946534/measurability-of-1-f/1946544?noredirect=1#comment3996389_1946544), and that the book's answer is also correct (though unnecessarily complicated). Questions about _why_ the author(s) chose to present it that way is probably best directed at the author(s), and not at a random guy on the internet.